# How can I load multiple XML documents inside my PHP, DOM script?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have two different XML structured documents, an XSLT that renames the elements and nodes of them to satisfy both and a PHP code that will save them into a new XML doc.

This is the code I used for testing purposes, however how can I load two or more paths like book1.xml and book2.xml into the `$xml` ? I know how to `$dom->load( 'book1.xml' );`

```
<?php

// create an XSLT processor and load the stylesheet as a DOM 
$xproc = new XsltProcessor();
$xslt = new DomDocument;
$xslt->load('stylesheet.xslt');    // this contains the code from above
$xproc->importStylesheet($xslt);


// your DOM or the source XML (copied from your question)
$xml = '';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);


?>
```

Comment: I guess a solution would be to have an array with all the XMLs and then use a foreach loop maybe?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for several possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read about and use the standard XSLT function [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document).**

In XSLT 2.0 there is also standard support for producing multiple result documents -- read about the **[`<xsl:result-document>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document)** element.

**If you are bound to XSLT 1.0, you cannot produce more than one result document in one transformation**. You can either use extension libraries (EXSLT, the **[`<exsl:document>`](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html)** extension element) or you can produce all results in one result document and then produce every single result out of it using another transformation, that you run once for producing each result.

Comment: I am using 2.0. So to clear my mind, I load multiple documents in the begining of an XSLT like `load('books1.xml', 'books2.xml')` and it makes the transform? If so how does this change my PHP code? Is there any working example to understand it better?

Comment: @Sampas: Are you sure? Which XSLT processor are you using? Can you use `<xsl:sequence>` in your code? Remember that just specifying `version="2.0"` doesn't mean you would be able to have your XSLT 2.0 code exacuted -- you must be using an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Oh, i just specified the version="2.0". How can I knoe what I am using? I am on a CPanel shared hosting (if it matters)

Comment: Sampas you may take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297445/how-to-handle-multiple-xpath-at-once-based-on-feed-structure-or-create-my-own-f is an answer Dimitre gave me. It may help you.

Comment: @Sampas: AFAIK, PHP programmers usually use XSLTProc and this is a 1.0 processor. There are only a few XSLT 2.0 processors -- Saxon 9.x, AltovaXML, XQSharp and two others (not free) -- from IBM and Intel.